# Mod_Rewrite with .htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just learnt about url-rewrite for my website with .htacess. My actual url is:

`localhost/index.php?view=some-page`

So i write this RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule  ^/([^/]*)/?$   /index.php?view=$1 [NC,L]
```

When i typed `localhost/homepage` on my browser, It does not work, it displays error 404 object not found. What have i done wrong please show me.

Many thanks

Comment: Is `RewriteEngine` set to `on`? Setting [logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) to higher level may help debugging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Leading slash is not matched in htaccess.

Comment: what is QSA flag do in this case please?

Comment: `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one. DId it work for you?

Comment: yah it work. I tried to leave out QSA it also works.

Comment: Yes `QSA` is not must to have but good to have. In case original URI is `/some-page?foo=bar` then with `QSA` this rule will make it to: `/index.php?view=some-page&foo=bar`. Without `QSA` it will become `/index.php?view=some-page` leaving original query string.

Answer (score 0):

are you using apache?

This link from step 6 helped me

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04

When i was playing around with rewrites i had to enable it and tell apache where the pages were stored